# Service Cloud Voice Demo Connector Issue

Tags: service-cloud-voice

I am trying to install the Service Cloud Voice demo connector using the instructions listed in this github;

https://github.com/salesforce/demo-scv-connector

And at the moment I do npm start and go to localhost:3030 it always shows me this error in the explorer "Cannot GET /".

I have also generated the certificate with OpenSSL and installed it and put it in the ca folder.

The idea I have is to be able to connect to my Service Cloud Voice instance to be able to simulate calls. But I can't get the package installed. And apart from the official documentation, I can't find much more information.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or explain me what are the steps you have followed to make it work?

I have the feeling that the guide is missing steps that are not explained.

Thank you.